# How to deserialize JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to work with a JSON result. but I did not understand this case.

```
{
    "result": {
        "employers": [
            {
                "nome": "Maria",
                "id": 2,
                "setor": "Setor1"
            },
            {
                "nome": "Abreu",
                "id": 4,
                "setor": "Setor2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employers ll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employers>(jsonString);
    Console.WriteLine(ll);
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to have `List<Employers> l1` rather than `Employers l1`.The following properties `nome`, `id` and `setor` should also be defined in the `Employers` class.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: You must include the exact error message you receive. Nobody can guess that from your code alone.

Comment: I think you might even have to deserialize a `Result` object containing the `List<Employer>` @DarrenDavies mentioned.

Comment: @AntonSizikov I dont know how send result to a employer list.

Comment: the only errors i see is the `Console.WriteLine(ll);` might not have a `ToString()` override. and possibly the `Employers` class does not match the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Employer
{
    [JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("setor")]
    public string Setor { get; set; }
}

class Employers : List<Employer>
{
}

Employers employers = JObject.Parse(json)["result"]["employers"].ToObject<Employers>();
```

Comment: thnks work perfect man.